# ibatis insert mapping

Tags: ibatis

I have the following model where class A can have multiple innerClass values similar to a Map.

```
class A{
 String id;
 public List<A.innerClass> getChildren(){
    return this.children;
 }
 static class innerClass{
  String name;
  String email;
 }
}
```

I want to insert it into a table(id, name , email) so the table should look like
        1, 'name1' 'email1'
        1, 'name2' 'email2'
        my sql map is

```
     <insert id="" parameterClass="A">
            <iterate property="children">
            INSERT 
                INTO table(colum1,colum2,coulum3)
                VALUES (#children[].innerClass[].name#, #children[].innerClass[].email#, #id#)
            </iterate>

        </insert>
```

but this leads to exceptions, would appreciate if someone could point me to the right syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your code, there's a problem at this line:

VALUES (#children[].innerClass[].name#, #children[].innerClass[].email#, #id#)

It should be changed into:

VALUES (#children[].name#, #children[].email#, #id#).

Refer to this link for more information: [iBatis dynamic SQL](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html)